# Powershell script pass Date (Custom Format) as Parameter

Tags: powershell

I have looked around but can't seem to find an exact answer to my question. I am writing a Powershell script that should run until it reaches the End_Date provided as a parameter by the user.

```
Param(
[Parameter][DateTime]$end_date
)
```

With the above code when i call the script it will ask me to provide a date. The problem is it expects a long format of the date and I just want to give it Day/Month/Year like 28/08/2016 but i can't figure out how. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://techontip.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/powershell-trick-converting-user-input-to-date/

```
$TD = Read-Host "Enter Date in mm-dd-yyyy Format"
$TD  #Echo input
[DateTime]$TD  #Convert back to long format
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="InputDate Format: dd-mm-yyyy")]
[ValidateScript({[DateTime]::ParseExact($_, "dd-MM-yyyy", $null)})]
$InputDate
)
```